# How Can I Iterate over the properties array with the array .forEach function in the displaySelectedUser function and display the properties in the UI

Tags: javascript, html

I'm Current doing this homework and it requires me to Iterate over variable, properties with the array `.forEach()` function, and display the properties in the UI. Hint: * a given property like *Age has a corresponding SPAN element with a data-age-value attribute. You can use ES6 template strings to build the query selector targeting the SPAN for that property, and then query the DOM with it. You also want to make sure you only update the UI if the DOM query was successful. This is to be done in the `displaySelectedUser()` arror function.

The ES6 template Strings doesnt seem to recognize the span tag using document.querySelector. I have tried applying the ES6 template string to just the `${props}` element but it was to no avail

```
<script>
      const users = [];


      const computeBMI = ({weight,height,country}) => {


        const healthyCountries = ["Chad","Sierra Leone","Mali","Gambia","Uganda","Ghana","Senegal","Somalia","Ivory Coast","isreal"];

        const bmiRate = 0.82;      
        let heightInMeters = height * 0.3048;
        let BMI = weight / Math.pow(heightInMeters,2);
        if (healthyCountries.includes(country)) {
          BMI *= bmiRate;
        }
        return Number(BMI.toFixed(2));
      };


      const getSelectedUser = (userId) => {
        return users.find(({id}) => id === userId);
         };


      const displaySelectedUser = ({target}) => {
        const user = getSelectedUser(target.value);

        const properties = Object.keys(user);

        properties.forEach(props => {


          const iterate = document.querySelector(`span[data-${props}-value]`);
          if(iterate !== ""){
            iterate.textContent = user[props];          
          }
        });
      };


      const letsCalculateBMI = () => {
        const query = document.querySelector('.select-text').value;
        const user = getSelectedUser(query);
        const bmi = computeBMI(user);
        document.querySelector('.bmi-text').textContent = bmi;

      };


      const powerupTheUI = () => {
        document.querySelector('.select-text').addEventListener('change', displaySelectedUser);

        document.querySelector('#oracle').addEventListener('click', letsCalculateBMI);
      };

      const displayUsers = (users) => {

        const select = document.querySelector('.select-text');
        users.forEach(user => {
          const option = document.createElement('option');
          option.value = user.id;
          option.textContent = user.name;
          select.appendChild(option);
        }); 
      };

      const fetchAndDisplayUsers = () => {
        users.push(
        {
          age: 40,
          weight: 75,
          height: 6,
          country: 'Nigeria',
          name: 'Charles Odili',
          id: 'dfhb454768DghtF'
        },
        {
          age: 26,
          weight: 80,
          height: 5.5,
          country: 'Mali',
          name: 'Mohammed Salah',
          id: 'jdks468654Galsh'
        }
        );

        displayUsers(users);
      };

      const startApp = () => {
        powerupTheUI();
        fetchAndDisplayUsers();
      };

      startApp();
</script>
```

// HTML Code

```
<body>
    <button id="filter-query" class="mdc-icon-button material-icons">filter_list</button>
    <div class="select">
      <select class="select-text">
        <option disabled selected>Select User</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="user-photo">
      <img src="" alt="User Photo">
    </div>
    <div class="details mdc-elevation--z3">
      <p><span class="prop" data-age>Age: </span>
        <span class="value" data-age-value></span></p>
      <p><span class="prop" data-height>Height: </span>
        <span class="value" data-height-value></span></p>
      <p><span class="prop" data-weight>Weight: </span>
        <span class="value" data-weight-value></span></p>
      <p><span class="prop" data-gender>Gender: </span>
        <span class="value" data-gender-value></span></p>
      <p><span class="prop" data-country>Country: </span>
        <span class="value" data-country-value></span></p>
    </div>

    <button id="oracle" class="mdc-button">Calculate BMI</button>

    <div id="outcome">
      <h1 class="mdc-typography--headline5">BMI</h1>
      <p class="bmi-text"></p>
    </div>
<body>
```

The result i Expect is for the `querySelector` to use the ES6 template string to  select the span tags containing the properties `data-age-value`, `date-height-value`, `data-weight-value` and `data-country-value` and write into the corresponding `span` tags the corresponding value of age,height,weight and country using the `properties.forEach()` loop in the `displaySelectedUser = ({target})` 
arrow function.

Comment: the code you have written is correct. I will confirm your selector is correctly utilizing the ES6 string template literal syntax. You've established code and expected output, but you've not said a word about errors in the console or other error conditions. What can you tell us about errors and what the variable `iterate` contains inside that loop?